# how to login in symfony with an external post call that return a json with a status

Tags: symfony, authentication, roles

login in symfony with an external post call that return a json

```
 <form class="form-signin" action="example.com/user/login"method="post">


                 {% if is_granted('ROLE_APP') %}
                  You are logged 
                 {% else %}
                 You are not logged !
                 {% endif %}


   <label for="inputEmail" class="sr-only">Username</label>
   <input type="text" name="username" class="form-control" placeholder="username" required autofocus>
   <label for="inputPassword" class="sr-only">Password</label>


   <input type="password" name="password" class="form-control" placeholder="password" required>


 <button class="btn btn-lg btn-primary btn-block" type="submit">Sign in</button>
```

if a call the external api return the json correct but how can i set the role of the user that in json return with ok?

thanks

Answer (score 0):

Instead of setting form action as `action="example.com/user/login"` set is to some action in your controller. Then in that controller call external api, read json, and if everything is ok, then login user programmatically. For example:

```
public function handleExternalApiLogin(Request $request, $token, GuardAuthenticatorHandler $handler, LoginFormAuthenticator $loginFormAuthenticator)
{
    ... //<- call external api and check if everything is ok

    $user = ... //get user that you want to be logged

    if ($user) {
        $handler->authenticateUserAndHandleSuccess($user, $request, $loginFormAuthenticator, 'main'); // <- here 'main' is your firewall name

        return $this->redirectToRoute('some_route_to_redirect_user_to');
    }

    return $this->redirectToRoute('route_where_login_form_is');
}
```

Comment: /**
     * @Route("/app")
     */
    public function appAction(Request $request, $token, GuardAuthenticatorHandler $handler, LoginFormAuthenticator $loginFormAuthenticator)
    {
        
    $status = '200';
     
    if ($status = '200') {
        $handler->authenticateUserAndHandleSuccess($user, $request, $loginFormAuthenticator, 'main'); // <- here 'main' is your firewall name

        return $this->redirectToRoute('esterne/app.account2.html.twig');
    }

    return $this->redirectToRoute('esterne/app.html.twig');
      
    }

Comment: but don't understand if it's ok :(